# certificate-based authentication on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, iis, outlook-web-app

We are using a IIS Server to authenticate the user with a certificate against OWA (Outlook Web Access) on Android phones and iPhones with the Google Chrome Browser.

The authentication is working fine.
But when the device has more than one certificate the user gets a pop-up to choose the right certificate. And the selection is not saved in the Google Chrome Browser. So every time the user wants to access OWA, he has to choose the correct certificate again.

Is there a way to bypass this pop-up? And is there a way to store the selection?

Thanks.

Comment: Determine client certificate is pure client certificate. Is it acceptable to set IIS Client certificate certificate to accept instead of require?

Comment: The certificate is a client / user certificate with the username as common name for expample. It is a pure client certificate I guess, yes. Accept instead of require is acceptable too.